# Where to inject AndroidInjection in custom/util classes using dagger2 in java android

Tags: java, android, class, dagger-2

I am using dagger 2. And injecting my dependency in activities and fragments which is working fine.

`AndroidInjection.inject(this)` for activities inside `onCreate`.

```
// for the activity
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```

`AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)` for fragments inside `onAttach`.

```
// for fragments
override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
    super.onAttach(context)
}
```

Now i want to inject my same dependency in a custom or util class named `AsyncTaskHandler`. I am not able to access that dependency.

I suppose i have to add `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` line somewhere. but it does not have any `onCreate` or `onAttach` function. So how to get the dependency accessible in my util class or to how to call that dependency.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do it in init()/Constructor  block that is the entry point of ur custom class and declare the variable as public and put a @inject annotation. It should work.

Comment: When i add this line
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);
It show red line below with error: "Cannot resolve method 'inject(com.my.app...)'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:
You could inject in the base application or AppModule

```
@Provides
MyUtilClass provideMyUtilClass(Context context) {
    return new MyUtilClass(context)
}
```

Following is a dummy util class you're trying to inject:

```
public class MyUtilClass  {
    private Context context;

    public MyUtilsClass (Context context) {
        this.context = context
   }
   // more code
}
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks @Ronan. But if i am calling this in the base class 'new MyUtilClass(context)'. The whole concept of dependency injection is lost. You are telling me to just wrap the new() in a provide method. This can not achieve the concept of DI

Comment: I have the dependent class ready. I am calling it using @Inject MyApi myApi; at the top. then adding this line in onCreate "AndroidInjection.inject(this);". Afterwards i am able to use myApi anywhere in this class. Now where to call "AndroidInjection.inject(this);" or anything in replacement of this in my modular or custom class which is not an activity or fragment class.

Comment: Thanks, @Jeff. I cannot comment based on my reputation. @Sajid the detailed information below should suffice to make you understand how `AndroidInjection(this)` works. Btw, how are you going to get the context if you're not creating a constructor and passing in context as a parameter?

Comment: @Ronan I agree with you; we answered the same question different ways. As long as the class accepts dependencies rather than creating them, it's DI. I disagree with Sajid that calling `new` from a Provides method is not DI; it's perfectly reasonable, and allows the caller to specify the dependency implementations, it simply doesn't use Dagger to its fullest potential. The part this answer doesn't address is how to get to MyUtilClass from other objects, which is why my answer is a bit higher-level to complement yours.

Comment: Thanks @JeffBowman for your detailed answer. I appreciate that. The point you made clear. so i am doing the solution now as Ronan advised. 
Thanks both of you for your time. I appreciate this. :)

Answer (score 5):

AndroidInjection is not meant to help with classes that are not subclasses of the Android framework. Instead, you are expected to do one of the following:

- In your DI-enabled class (Activity, Fragment, etc, or anything they inject), inject AsyncTaskHandler or `Provider<AsyncTaskHandler>` through an `@Inject`-annotated constructor or field. This will give you a fully-injected AsyncTaskHandler, and the Provider will give you as many as you may need (including zero). This also allows you to replace AsyncTaskHandler or its factory in different configurations, or to replace the AsyncTaskHandler instance in tests.
- If AsyncTaskHandler is an implementation detail that you don't need to replace, even in tests, you can call `new AsyncTaskHandler`. The use of DI doesn't imply that every single class is injected. Of course, if AsyncTaskHandler has a lot of dependencies, you may choose to inject for the sake of convenience and configurability even if you do not intend to replace AsyncTaskHandler itself in any configuration.
- If you *must* have AsyncTaskHandler inject itself even when there is no enclosing DI environment, you can craft your own solution: Make sure that AsyncTaskHandler has access to the Application instance, cast it to an interface that allows for injection, and then inject it using a [members-injection method](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.19/dagger/Component.html#members-injection-methods). You may also choose to save your Component or a [`MembersInjector<AsyncTaskHandler>`](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.19/dagger/MembersInjector.html) into a static field somewhere, and access that to allow for injecting your AsyncTaskHandler—potentially keeping the static field on AsyncTaskHandler itself. You'll want to do that on `Application#onCreate` or wherever you create your Component instance.

  The difficulty of procuring an Application instance from an arbitrary class instance without relying on a test-unfriendly static injector, or in ensuring that a static field is populated with a Component or MembersInjector whenever your AsyncTaskHandler needs it, is part of the reason that AndroidInjection is limited in its scope to exclude this type of use-case. You'll need to make sure the rest of your code is structured in such a way that this is safe.